# Updating the checkbox value based on the backend reponse using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to do an edit function, Where I'll get the data from the backend. So if the value of dependents is '1,2' then box the checkbox should be selected. I should be able to unselect the checkbox and send the value again if needed. In the below one, When we click on the add for the second row I'm checking if value of check box as 2 (line:79) and it's showing as checked. The problem is when I'm unable to unselect it and send it again.

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-rhodes-i2sn9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code a bit,
`dependents` state cannot handle dependents of all form values, so I have added a dependent object inside the form values object,
I have tested it and it is working,
Only the code and logic for checkbox is modified  all other codes is similar to yours

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-ubcz4

try this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState([
    { orderno: 1, inputValue1: "", inputValue2: "", dependentParams: [] }
  ]);
  const [dependents, setDependents] = useState("");

  // control order number in a state to make sure
  // that it does not get messed when you remove
  // an indice from formValues
  // !! default was 0. so set it to 1
  const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState(1);

  const addFormFields = () => {
    let dependentString = [];
    formValues.map((d, i) => {
      dependentString.push(i + 1);
    });
    setFormValues((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        orderno: orderNumber + 1,
        inputValue1: "",
        inputValue2: "",
        dependentParams: dependentString.length ? dependentString : []
      }
    ]);
    // increment order number
    setOrderNumber((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const removeFormFields = (i) => {
    let newFormValues = [...formValues];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);

    setFormValues(newFormValues);

    // decrement order number
    setOrderNumber((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  const onChangeFieldValue = (index, key, value) => {
    setFormValues((prevState) => {
      let copyState = [...prevState];
      copyState[index][key] = value;
      return copyState;
    });
  };
  const onchangeCheckbox = (e, orderNo, index) => {
    setFormValues((prevState) => {
      let copyState = [...prevState];
      let dependentParams = [...copyState[orderNo].dependentParams];
      console.log(index, dependentParams);
      if (dependentParams.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
        dependentParams.splice(dependentParams.indexOf(index), 1);
      } else {
        dependentParams.push(index);
      }
      copyState[orderNo].dependentParams = dependentParams;
      return copyState;
    });
  };

  const saveFields = (e) => {
    const queryparam = {
      data: "xxx",
      DbData: "xxx",
      SQlData: "xxx", // only checked ones
      overallData: { formValues : formValues.map(d => ({...d, dependentParams:d.dependentParams.join(',')})) }
    };
    console.log(queryparam, "hhhhhhh");
  };

  const rows = (ele, orderno) => {
    let rowNos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < orderno; i++) {
      rowNos.push(
        <>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={orderno - i}
            id={orderno - i}
            checked={ele.dependentParams.indexOf(orderno - i) !== -1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              onchangeCheckbox(e, orderno, orderno - i);
            }}
          />
          Params {orderno - i}
        </>
      );
    }
    return rowNos;
  };
  return (
    <>
      {formValues.length <= 4
        ? formValues.map((element, index) => (
            <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
              <label>{index + 1}</label>

              <input
                type="text"
                value={element.inputVal1}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  onChangeFieldValue(index, "inputValue1", e.target.value)
                }
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                value={element.inputVal2}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  onChangeFieldValue(index, "inputValue2", e.target.value)
                }
              />
              {rows(element, index)}

              <button
                className="button add"
                type="button"
                onClick={() => addFormFields()}
              >
                Add
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="button remove"
                onClick={() => removeFormFields(index)}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </div>
          ))
        : ""}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button remove"
        onClick={(e) => saveFields(e)}
      >
        Save
      </button>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="button remove"
        //onClick={(e) => cancelFields(e)}
      >
        cancel
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: While sending data as well as from the backend the dependentParams value will come as string not as an array or obj.For example, second row as value "1" and for 3 row as depdenpdent param value is '1,2', For 4th row as '1,2,3'  if all the check boxes are selected. Not as an array it will be a string.

Comment: Yes, i have used that `dependentParams`  array for an example you could use it how it needed to be, just change that array of objects to a string array or a string itself and on each checkbox check whether the `index + 1` exists or not in `dependentParams` if exists return true to checked if not then return false to checked, Show me the final data sample which you needed  to send to server I will modify the code based on that

Comment: I tried and with string the prev state is not working for the second row.Its showing as "". My Data to server will be  [{orderno: 1,
        inputValue1: "",
        inputValue2: "",
        dependentParams: ""},{orderno: 2,
        inputValue1: "",
        inputValue2: "",
        dependentParams: "1" // if param 1 is  checked.if its not checked then it will ""} {orderno: 2,
        inputValue1: "",
        inputValue2: "",
        dependentParams: "1,2"/ /if param 1,2 is  checked.if its not checked then it will ""

Comment: show me the result data you needed to send to server

Comment: {"data":"xxx","DbData":"xxx","SQlData":"xxx","overallData":{"formValues":[{"orderno":1,"inputValue1":"tes123","inputValue2":"tes123","dependentParams":""},{"orderno":2,"inputValue1":"tes123","inputValue2":"tes123","dependentParams":"1"},{"orderno":3,"inputValue1":"tes123","inputValue2":"tes123","dependentParams":"1,2"},{"orderno":4,"inputValue1":"tes123","inputValue2":"tes123","dependentParams":"1,3"}]}}

Comment: In the above one, I did'nt click on param 2 checkbox for orderNo:4. So..it will not be added as depedentParams

Comment: Understood, will update code in 20 minutes

Comment: In the above one, we are unable to uncheck the checkbox and send the response again

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer, use it in your local environment

Comment: Can you please post it in codesandbox.'Cause When I tried .. I'm unable to uncheck the value and send it again

Comment: @HemaNandagopal https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-ubcz4 check this, same also updated in answer

Comment: Yea, with index+1 its doing the same

Answer (score 0):

Change checkbox checked attribute condition to

```
 checked={orderno === 1 ? true : false}
```

and try again

Comment: I tried this with null too, I could'nt uncheck the value again and send it to the backend,